# how to get values from an ArrayList<Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>>>

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashtable

I have a function that is capable to read data from multiple files with the following structure:

```
id  date    temp    psal
1   2016/02/01  37.6    35.9
2   2016/02/02  30.3    35.7
3   2016/02/03  28.2    36.8
4   2016/02/04  27.7    37.7
5   2016/02/05  28.7    37.9
6   2016/02/06  28.7    37.9
```

The function is:

```
ArrayList<Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>>> processedFilesArray = ReadFiles(files);
```

If I try to retrieve the data by using for example:

```
System.out.println(processedFilesArray.get(0));
```

Then I get the following response:

```
{Psals=[35.9, 35.7, 36.8, 37.7, 37.9, 37.9], Temps=[37.6, 30.3, 28.2, 27.7, 28.7, 28.7], ids=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], DateStrings=[2016/02/01, 2016/02/02, 2016/02/03, 2016/02/04, 2016/02/05, 2016/02/06]}
```

My question is:
How can I obtain the different values of the keys (Temps, Psals, ids, etc) by sepparate to plot them using jfreechart?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you build the `ArrayList<Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>>>` yourself? If so, it's the wrong data structure (effectively a "parallel arrays" structure).  You should define a class to hold one line of input as an object.

Comment: As @JimGarrison said, you should reconsider your data structure.

Comment: Hi, thanks to all for your quick responses. Actually I didn't build this structure completely by myself. However I understand your comments about creating a class, and this probably will be my next step as I am currently learning about the objects phylosophy

Answer (score 2):

You can get list of keys in your Hashtable by method [**keySet()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()), which return Set of Keys.

You can convert Set to Array list like this :-

> ArrayList keyList = new
>   ArrayList(processedFilesArray.get(0).keySet());

More about keySet http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_keyset.htm

Comment: Thanks for your response Hitesh. I solved it by using the values instead of keySet. However your response was useful to me in order to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the keys and values by this way:

```
//Each hastTable of proccesedFilesArray
     for(Hashtable<String,ArrayList<String>> processedFile : processedFilesArray){
        //Each entrySet of proccesedFile
        for(Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : processedFile.entrySet()){
            //Filter here by key or value with if conditions
            String key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<String> listValue = entry.getValue();//List of Strings
            for(String value : listValue){
               //each value per hashtable key
            }

        }
    }
```

I dont really know how do you want to work with this but that could be a way to iterate your list and get the values of each record.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this issue following Hitesh response, by using:

```
ArrayList keyList = new ArrayList(processedFilesArray.get(1).values());
    System.out.println(keyList.get(0));
```

This returns me the first group (Psals) from the second file read:

```
    [35.9, 35.7, 36.8, 37.7, 37.9, 37.9]
```

Thank you guys for your help!!

Comment: This is very fragile since order is not guaranteed in Hashtable. Instead of accessing the values list by copying the collection returned by `Hashtable.values()` in an `ArrayList` and accessing these by index, you should prefer to access it this way: `processedFilesArray.get(i).get("Psals")`. Ideally, if you want to process all the elements in the `Hashtable`, you should use Manu AG's answer.

Comment: Thanks Valentin, it works better than my solution. I also agree with you in relation with Manu AG's solution.